# All Screen icons disappear/reappear at random

Tags: desktop-icons

Ubuntu 22.04.1 Every so often all screen icons disappear then reappear.
It occurs within ~2 seconds and has been happening for a few days only.
Very annoying. If I'm searching for a string inside editor this "bug" resets the search and I end up typing elsewhere.
At a guess a "trap" that DMESG reports seems to coincide with the "bug" occurrence.

```
traps: gjs[78084] trap int3 ip:7fcf23e98ccf sp:7fffae490260 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.1[7fcf23e59000+8f000]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks to Artur for correcting my English/Spanish overlapping spelling of "ocurrencia" and painting some nice colours. Do tell, as I am new to this forum, why the colours?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I attempted to update from 21.04  directly to 22.04.  Did you recently upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04? Apparently there is no upgrade path from there to 22.04.

I wrote it up and [someone answered me here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422766/upgraded-from-21-04-to-22-04-failure-now-have-flashing-desktop-icons-what-shou).

It could also be your windowing system...

Which windowing system are you running?

1. Wayland
2. X11 / Xorg

I had numerous problems while running Wayland, all of which were resolved when I [switched to Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412014/how-to-enable-xorg-option-at-ubuntu-22-04-login-screen/1431963#1431963).

Check which one you're running in System Settings...About...

Mine shown here shows I'm running X11, but yours may say Wayland.

[image: system settings]

It's likely that if you are running Wayland, that a change to X11 will fix the issue.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I did a clean install recently.
The windowing system is Wayland
The graphics controller is AMD® Radeon vega 8 graphics
I'll switch to X11 and see what happens tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Morning, changing to X11 DIDNT change the behaviour. I'm back to Wayland.
The traps are still occurring and coincide with the disapearring desktop icons.
l